# How to set canvas height to be Full Document height (Cover the whole page)

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

Heyy all,

Just getting ready for xmas so I had some snow falling using the Canvas and it looks really cool, although it is only fulling up via 100vh due to:

```
c.width = innerWidth;
c.height = innerHeight;
```

So if someone could help me out here I would much appreciate it =)

I have tried using via CSS:

```
canvas#c {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
bottom: 1px;
top: 1px;
height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who cares, I changed from position: absolute; to position: fixed;

Now it just stays in the screen looking like its snowing =)

Comment: Be aware that you _cannot_ click anything that is _under_ the canvas (the click would go to the canvas and not the elements under it). For modern browsers you can use `pointer-events:none` to ignore any pointer based interactions, but IE does not support that (so your site becomes unusable apart from scrolling). Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Figured that no links were working in my site so i just added position:relative to the A:link and gave it a z-index the same as the canvus. worked great!